# How to pass member to other member in a class data in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17

How to pass or organize member data in C++ ?
for example

```cpp
class A
{
public；
  uint8_t a;
};

class B
{
public；
  uint8_t b;
};

class Data
{
public:
 A a;
 B b;
}
```

ther is a data list

```
std::vector<data> datas;
```

now I must add Class C to Data

```
class C
{
void op1()
{
   // need get B.b;
}

void op2()
{
  // need get A.a;
}

private:
  uint8_t c;
}
```

add to class Data

```
class Data
{
public:
 A a;
 B b;
 C c;
}
```

In actual code, class C is a part of class Data and requires reading or modifying many other members which are also from class Data.
C also has some internally managed data that should not be public. In this case, how to organize the class structure is more appropriate.
I don't want to pass the refernces of other menber to C.This will make the structure look somewhat complex.

I tried to separate class C from Data,but class Data are in a list of DataDb.This means that it is necessary to construct a C list bound to the datalist.This is difficult to accept.

Comment: If `C` is not used anywhere else you could pass a `Data&` to `C`s constructor.

Comment: Change methods in `C` to `void C::op1(B&)`?

Comment: Somehow it seems the design is not right. Class C would need to know too much about class A and B. You could pass references to two int into the constuctor of class C (that seems to be the minimal dependency). Or you can make class A and B members of C and let data only interact with C (and forward getters to A and B).

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to pass the refernces of other menber to C.This will make the structure look somewhat complex.

You need *some* way of getting a reference to those `uint8_t`s all the way to `C::op1`. If each instance of `C` needs to access the same `A` and the same `B` for it's entire lifetime, the easiest way to ensure that is for `C` to get those references at construction time. Necessarily, this will complicate `Data`.